# How to convert multiple list in dictionary in python

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, jupyter

```
    # Create a dictionary out of below inputs
lst1 = ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3']
emp_key = ['e_name', 'e_id', 'e_sal']
emp1_val = ['John', 'SG101', '$10,000']
emp2_val = ['Smith', 'SG102', '$9,000']
emp3_val = ['Peter', 'SG103', '$9,500']

# Expected Output:- 
                    {'emp1':{'e_name':'John', 'e_id':'SG101', 'e_sal':$10,000}, 
                     'emp2':{'e_name':'Smith', 'e_id':'SG102', 'e_sal':$9,000}, 
                     'emp3':{'e_name':'Peter', 'e_id':'SG103', 'e_sal':$9,500}}
```

I need output like this tried with zip but its not working please suggest best way .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested list comprehension, using `dict` over [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) twice to form the nested dictionaries:

```py
lst1 = ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3']
emp_key = ['e_name', 'e_id', 'e_sal']
emp1_val = ['John', 'SG101', '$10,000']
emp2_val = ['Smith', 'SG102', '$9,000']
emp3_val = ['Peter', 'SG103', '$9,500']

result = dict(zip(lst1, [dict(zip(emp_key, e)) for e in [emp1_val, emp2_val, emp3_val]]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```py
{
 'emp1': {'e_name': 'John', 'e_id': 'SG101', 'e_sal': '$10,000'},
 'emp2': {'e_name': 'Smith', 'e_id': 'SG102', 'e_sal': '$9,000'},
 'emp3': {'e_name': 'Peter', 'e_id': 'SG103', 'e_sal': '$9,500'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *dictionary comprehension* with [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [**`enumerate()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to achieve this as:

```
lst1 = ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3']
emp_key = ['e_name', 'e_id', 'e_sal']
emp1_val = ['John', 'SG101', '$10,000']
emp2_val = ['Smith', 'SG102', '$9,000']
emp3_val = ['Peter', 'SG103', '$9,500']

# additional list to hold `emp*_val` together 
emp_values = [emp1_val, emp2_val, emp3_val]

my_dict = {emp: dict(zip(emp_key, emp_values[i])) for i, emp in enumerate(lst1)}
```

Here's an *alternative using **`zip()`** twice* (without using `enumerate()`):

```
my_dict = {emp: dict(zip(emp_key, emp_val)) for emp, emp_val in zip(lst1, emp_values)}
```

In both the above solutions, `my_dict` will give you:

```
{
    'emp2': {
        'e_sal': '$9,000', 
        'e_id': 'SG102', 
        'e_name': 'Smith'
    }, 
    'emp3': {
        'e_sal': '$9,500', 
        'e_id': 'SG103', 
        'e_name': 'Peter'
    }, 
    'emp1': {
        'e_sal': '$10,000', 
        'e_id': 'SG101', 
        'e_name': 'John'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`. For that you need to group `emp_key` with different `emp_val` and finally generate the `dict`.

```py
lst1 = ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3']
emp_key = ['e_name', 'e_id', 'e_sal']
emp1_val = ['John', 'SG101', '$10,000']
emp2_val = ['Smith', 'SG102', '$9,000']
emp3_val = ['Peter', 'SG103', '$9,500']

{f'emp{index}': dict(zip(emp_key, e)) for index, e in enumerate([emp1_val, emp2_val, emp2_val],1)}
```

```
{'emp1': {'e_name': 'John', 'e_id': 'SG101', 'e_sal': '$10,000'},
 'emp2': {'e_name': 'Smith', 'e_id': 'SG102', 'e_sal': '$9,000'},
 'emp3': {'e_name': 'Smith', 'e_id': 'SG102', 'e_sal': '$9,000'}}
```